# aws media files not showing

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend

I'm using aws s3 to store media files for a Django app, I install boto3 and django-storages. It uploads files to aws but the file does not render. I opened the link and see this message

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
<RequestId>15134F3A4F5CCB2B</RequestId>
<HostId>ieKre9JIipHoSqal7QUt/jTPQY5hdrsfI95cyLQAtVIjM8r+OnjhDIGYH6cDpJQr1wXu71foxek=</HostId>
</Error>
```

My configs are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID       = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY   = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE   = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL         = None
```

I really don't have much to go on from the error message, where do I use this `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` on aws? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into this problem, it turns out there are regions that does not support `Signature Version 2`. It's really hard to solve because I don't know where to change signature versions in my installed packages (django-storages and boto3).

So long story short I found this answer on [github](https://github.com/perkeep/perkeep/issues/911) with regions that don't support v2 and I was in one. Just create a new bucket in supported regions.